# Prove: if $\text{Re}(g)<\log(\varepsilon)$ and $|f\exp(-g)-h_0|<1$, then $|f-h_0\exp(g)|<\varepsilon$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\xrightarrow{}\mathbb{C}$ be continuous, $\varepsilon:\mathbb{R}\xrightarrow{}\mathbb{R}$ be a positive and continuous function, and $g$, $h_0$ be two entire functions.

> Prove: If $\text{Re}(g)<\log(\varepsilon)$ and $|f\exp(-g)-h_0|<1$, then
>
> $$|f-h_0\exp(g)|<\varepsilon.$$

My attempt:

Multiply by $|\exp(g)|$ on both sides to get

$$|\exp(g)|\cdot|f\exp(-g)-h_0|<|\exp(g)|$$ or $$|f-h_0\exp(g)|<|\exp(g)|$$

I don't know how to use $\exp(\text{Re}(g))<\varepsilon$. If I had $|\exp(g)|<\varepsilon$ this would be immediate, but what do I do with only the real part?

If anyone is interested, I'm reading this paper by Rudin and trying to complete the last proof:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fort any complex number $z$ we have $|e^{z}|=e^{Re(z)}$. Hence $|e^{g}|=e^{Re(g)}<e^{log(\epsilon)}=\epsilon$.